# Set one element at a time as 'active'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The easiest way for me to explain the question is by you looking at my code [at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cMTUh/)

each Div has only one link which once clicked sets the Div to active + shows a hidden Div within it. So when you click the link again it toggles the active style and hides the hidden Div. this is how I want it, but i am also wanting it so that if I click on another link and the previous Div is still set to active it will only set that Div(just clicked) as active and toggle the previous div.

I hope this makes sense if you need any more info let me know.

Also If you see a better way of coding this little piece of code, I would love suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your markup guarantees that all of the related divs are siblings, this works (and without using any IDs or attributes):

```
$('.href').click(function (ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    // find enclosing div
    var p = $(this).closest('div');

    // make this one active, and make others inactive
    $(p).addClass('active')
        .siblings('.active').removeClass('active').find('.hidden').hide();

   // and change the hidden div
    $(p).find('.hidden').toggle();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/y8kys/

The middle line does the hard work - it ensures the outer div has the right class, that none of its siblings does, and that the hidden elements in every sibling are also hidden.

I put another version at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ZfhbU/ which works when the enclosing divs aren't siblings.

Comment: Thanks for your time, and thank you for providing two sets of code. I believe that the first piece will do what is needed as the structure of the markup will not be changing. Thank you again :)

Comment: just realised - for best performance put a `'.active'` selector in the `.siblings()` call.  It'll avoid making irrelevant updates to siblings that are still inactive.

Answer (score 1):

Before showing the hidden `div`, you can check all of the other hidden `div` elements, hide them if necessary, and toggle the style on the parent `div`:

```
$('.hidden').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(":visible")) {
       $(this).hide("slow");
       $(this).parent().toggleClass("active");
    }
});
```

See an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/cMTUh/3/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I noticed that with the code you had you have to click on the link 4 times to get it back to the original state.

Comment: Indeed it does... here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/cMTUh/3/